# Remove html wrap codes and keep contents only if line contains something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are so many rows which looks like :

```
<div class="info"><ul><li><b><a href="http://www.domain1.com/10166/a-l-f/" title="ALF" target="_blank">ALF</a></b>[some text here]<a href="http://www.domain2.com/50367/DMS/" title=... blah blah blah
```

I want to delete every link which contains domain1.com and keep only it's contents (such as ALF) .
I've tried this code :

```
$('a[href*="domain1"]').removeAttr('href');
```

but it will only remove href tag , Not the entire a tag.
I want to remove entire a tag and only keep it's content.
I've also used these codes but nothing happend , just errors !

```
$("a[href*="domain1"]").replaceWith(function () {
return $(this).text();
});
```

&

```
$('a[href*="domain1"]').contents().unwrap();
```

&

```
$("a:contains(domain1)").find("a.link").contents().unwrap();
```

But still nothing happens!

Comment: `href` is an attribute of the `a` tag, so using `removeAttr('href')` will only remove the link portion, but leave the `a` tag itself.  When you say you want to "remove entire a tag and only keep its content", do you mean change it to a `p` tag or something?

Comment: What's wrong with your first `contents().unwrap()` method? It [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/gs2bLc4p/).

Comment: Yes , I got it worked ! It seems the problem comes from Jquery version which I was trying to run the code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in the selector here:

```
$("a[href*="domain1"]").replaceWith(function () {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

You can't have double quotes in a string without escaping them. Try: `"a[href*=\"domain1\"]"` or use single quotes for your string, `'a[href*="domain1"]'`. That should work.

Comment: I've tried , Both returns : TypeError: $(...).replaceWith is not a function

Comment: @Mostafa Which jQuery version are you running?